# How to run Google Bigquery query from dev machine (localhost)

Tags: java, localhost, google-bigquery, remote-access

How can I connect to Google BigQuery 'table' from Java app on my dev machine (localhost) and query the table in BigQuery?

I am using the BigQuery java library https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries

We want to deploy our java web application on-premise and send some data to BigQuery.

Comment: Can you clarify what you tried already and what doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible ways:

1. **Local development users** - create users in the project for every developer, each will authenticate (gcloud auth ...) under their account and then the API client libs will just pick up the auth
2. **Service accounts** - create a service account, download the JSON file
   and use it for authentication. For this there are 2 ways: 1 file for everybody (but it's risky - security wise... you should rotate the file often) or 1 file (thus 1 service account) for each developer... but this is harder to manage.

As in the end the app will be on premise I would personally go for the service accounts approach.

See more at https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication